# Exception when using multiple text boxes in C# to update an Access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

My code is throwing this exception:

> Syntax Error in UPDATE statement

What's wrong with my SQL syntax? How do I fix it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and an Access database. Here's my code:

```
private void CBM_editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // to edit or update already existing informations
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
        con.ConnectionString =
          @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Sunquick\Desktop\c sharp project2\ContactBook2.mdb";

        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
        com.CommandText = "UPDATE ContactList set Name='" + CBM_textbox1.Text +
          "','" + CBM_textbox2.Text + "','" + CBM_textbox3.Text +
          "','" + CBM_textbox4.Text + "','" + CBM_textbox5.Text + "'";

        com.Connection = con;
        con.Open();
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Data has been changed");
        con.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception Error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Error.ToString());
    }

    CBM_textbox1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: You have a stray `)` at the end of your UPDATE and you don't have a WHERE clause on it either.

Comment: Security tip: To avoid SQL injection attacks in you application, consider using parameterized queries.

Comment: Thanks to " mu is too short" and "Espen Burud" you guys really helped me out! its my first individual class project in c-Sherp! Finally its working with all of your help and i am going to submit it!

Comment: Another quick tip. OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand are disposable and you should wrap them in a using block. If you look at the class documentation on MSDN for either one, they give examples of how to wrap them properly. It's good practice to wrap disposable objects in using blocks to properly release their respective resources.

Answer (score 2):

```
com.CommandText = "UPDATE ContactList set Name='" + CBM_textbox1.Text + 
   "', Email='" + CBM_textbox2.Text + "', Mobile='" + CBM_textbox3.Text + 
   "', Country='" + CBM_textbox4.Text + "', City='" + CBM_textbox5.Text + "')"
```

2nd to last character is a ')'  -  where did that come from

(Also, you don't have a where clause, so you're updating the whole table)

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what's going on I guess.

Comment: Also, since you're not using parameterized query, text within the text box can also be 'injected' into the query.  This is really bad if they add (in CBM_Textbox5) the value of: 'Canton; drop table ContactList'

Comment: Thank you  J. Vermeire and thank you Ray K! you guys really helped me out! its our first individual class project in c-Sherp! Finally its working with all of your help and i am going to submit it!

Answer (score 2):

If one of your textboxes contains a text with a single quote, this will create an invalid sql statement.

As others have pointed out, you could use paramtrized queries. Nevertheless, I show you a string version.

It uses this helper function

```
private string SqlStr(string s) 
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) {
        return "NULL";
    }
    return "'" + s.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```

Try this:

```
string sql = String.Format(
    "UPDATE ContactList SET Name={0}, Email={1}, Mobile={2}, Country={3}, City={4}",
    SqlStr(CBM_textbox1.Text),
    SqlStr(CBM_textbox2.Text),
    SqlStr(CBM_textbox3.Text),
    SqlStr(CBM_textbox4.Text),
    SqlStr(CBM_textbox5.Text)
);
```

Your sql example has a superfluous ")" at the end and since a WHERE statement is missing, it will update the whole table! You should add something like this:

```
"... WHERE id=77"
```

Or may be you were trying to add a record? In which case you should have used something like:

```
INSERT INTO ContactList (Name, Email, City) VALUES ('John','jd@xx.com','LA')
```

Comment: Thank you so much "Olivier Jacot-Descombes" you really helped me! its our first individual class project in c-Sherp! Finally its working with all of your help! great work! :)